# I want to move my OS from one machine to another

Tags: windows

I have Windows 8 running on a computer but the hard drive is always spiking to 99% and it becomes really laggy. I'd like to move it over to a new machine. Is there anyway I can do this without having to reinstall the OS and my applications? I'd like to keep my set up.

Comment: I think what you're looking to do is clone your hard drive (or partition(s)). This can be done by creating an *image* of it with imaging software.

Comment: From there I can install it on any other hardware?

Comment: You're going to find it difficult to just take an image of your current PC and port it over to a PC with different hardware. You're going to come across all sorts of driver issues, if it boots at all.

Comment: Beware that if you have an OEM copy of windows, it will detect the change of hardware and request reactivation, for which you will need a new product key, as will any other software installed as OEM

Comment: I have an MSDN account, could I use one of those keys?

Comment: @Batman - Yes...

Comment: @Batman, you might want to spend some time figuring out why your disk is spiking.  You also want to make sure that the new computer has a faster hard drive (or you'll just be in the same spot with a different computer).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [DriveImage](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). It can clone drives so you can just plug in the new drive and clone to it.
But do be careful with new hardware... it may not work

Answer (score 0):

Using the same disk image may not work with your other computer because of different hardware. I recommend a fresh install of operating system to avoid loss of time.

However if you are determined to try "moving" your OS, I recommend [Redo Backup](http://redobackup.org/). It is free, open source, reliable and very simple to use.

Using Redo, take a backup of your disk image to an external hard disk or to a network point and then restore that image to your other computer using Redo again.

1. Download Redo Backup CD image from its [website](http://redobackup.org/).
2. Write it to a CD or USB flash drive.
3. Plug in that CD or USB flash drive and turn your computer on.
4. Using boot options, make your computer boot from that CD/USB drive.
5. Click "Backup" or "Restore" icon on your screen and follow the simple instructions.